# How to ensure extreme? -- using Extreme Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization, maximum-principle

I think it's a simple question. How can I ensure the existence of an extreme (maximum or minimum) using the Extreme Value Theorem / Weierstrass theorem?

For example, this multivariate case:
$$
F(x,y)=\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{x^3}{3}+x^2 y - y^2 -3y.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you simply can't. Essentially there is no general tool for locating *local* extrema. Weierstrass' Theorem applies only to continuous functions defined on compact sets, but is totally useless in other cases.

Think of the function $f(x)=x+\sin x$, which possesses a sequence of local extrema. However, it is very hard to predict their existence without solving $f'(x)=0$ and checking the nature of each zero of the derivative. As you can imagine, the situation gets even harder for functions of several variable, since you can approach a point along infinitely many directions.

Comment: You are right. I saw this problem in a list of exercises but is poorly formulated (they forgot to say the domain of the function)... thank you!